# Getting function returned value

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a function "func" which gets two arguments "a" and "b" and returns something.
For some reason I can't manage echo what I get from the function.

This is what I tried:

```
value=$(func $a $b)
echo $value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't show your function definition, this is only a guess, but I'm pretty confident it's a good one.

You need to understand that a function in shell fits into the language as if it was a *command*, i.e. a separate program, and the `return` keyword is analogous to `exit`. You can only return small integers, and the caller sees them in `$?`, just like the exit value of any other command.

Functions can also output a result to `stdout` by using `echo` (or any other command that prints to stdout), and then the result can be caputred with `$(func args ...)`

So you probably just need to change `return` to `echo` in your function.

Comment: My function returns using "return" statement, since I want to finish the function once it returns some value.

Comment: So change it to an `echo` followed by a `return 0` if you want the function to be considered successful, or `return 1` if you want it to fail. Just like writing an independent program - you do your output then exit. Except the "exit" from a shell function is spelled "return".